# WEB SERVICE PHP MYSQL VALIDACION DE USUARIO CON JSON

Tags: php, mysql, android, json, webservice

Intento crear un web service que quiero consumir en una aplicacion movil, al momento que lo coloco en la url e inserto los datos me extrae lo que necesito pero los repite, ademas que cuando lo consumo en la app coloco datos errados y el igual pasa.

**Codigo del Web Service**

'$json=array();

```
if(isset($_GET["usuario"]) && isset($_GET["pass"])){
    $usuario=$_GET['usuario'];
    $pass=$_GET['pass'];
    
    $conexion=mysqli_connect($hostname_localhost,$usuarioname_localhost,$password_localhost,$database_localhost);
    
    $consulta="SELECT usuario, pass FROM user WHERE usuario= '{$usuario}' AND pass = '{$pass}'";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

    if($consulta){
    
        if($registro=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
            $json['datos'][]=$registro;
            
        }
        mysqli_close($conexion);
        echo json_encode($json);
    }



    else{
        $results["usuario"]='No Registra';
        $results["pass"]='No Registra';
        $results["nombre"]='No Registra';
        $json['datos']['']=$results;
        echo json_encode($json);
    }
    
}
else{
        $results["usuario"]='No Retorna';
        $results["pass"]='No Retorna';
        $results["nombre"]='No Retorna';
        $json['usuarios'][]=$results;
        echo json_encode($json);
    }'
```

[image: ph]

Este es el codigo que coloque en android studio para poder utilizar la parte del login, no se que estoy haciendo mal que el sigue entrando aun con datos errados en el usuario y contraseña

```
private void validarUsuario (String URL){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if(!response.isEmpty()){
                    Intent IniciarSecion = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),menu_principal.class);
                    startActivity(IniciarSecion);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Usuario o Contraseña Incorrecta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                 Map<String,String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
                 parametros.put("correo", edtusuario.getText().toString());
                 parametros.put("contrasena", edtpass.getText().toString());
                return super.getParams();

            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias cosas en tu código:

### 1. Siempre entra en el `if`

Esto ocurre porque estás usando `$consulta` para hacer la comparación. Pero `$consulta` no es otra cosa que tu instrucción SQL, y siempre será `true` (verdadero) porque no es otra cosa que una cadena. Debes basarte en los datos para hacer la comprobación.

### 2. Repite los datos

Esto ocurre porque el tipo de lectura que estás usando (`mysqli_fetch_array`) trae los datos como array asociativo y numérico. Puedes usar un método más específico como `mysqli_fetch_assoc` o `mysqli_fetch_row`.

Vamos a corregir lo antes dicho:

```
$consulta="SELECT usuario, pass FROM user WHERE usuario= '{$usuario}' AND pass = '{$pass}'";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

#(1) La comparación debe hacerse en base al número de filas
if( mysqli_num_rows($resultado)>0 ){
    #(2) Usamos un método de lectura específico
    if($registro=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
        $json['datos'][]=$registro;
    } else {
        #Convendría indicar si no hay filas. Aquí ponemos una clave error
        $json['datos']['error']="No se encontraron filas";
    mysqli_close($conexion);
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

---

### Recomendaciones

Te recomiendo que implementes consultas preparadas, ya que tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*.

Convendría también poner un `header` antes de la salida del JSON, y usar codificación UTF-8. En respuestas con acentos o caracteres especiales el JSON podría ser inválido y hacer que la App se detenga.

En comunicación de este tipo conviene controlar todas las posibles salidas. Para estandarizar el código puedes poner una clave `error` cuando ocurra algo inesperado (por ejemplo lo he hecho en el caso de que no haya filas), luego en el cliente (Android) verificas si el JSON tiene ese clave `error` para saber que algo mal ocurrió y decidir lo que debe hacer el código en el cliente para esos casos. No puedes dejar aspectos del código sin cubrir, pues la App se puede quedar en un limbo sin que el usuario comprenda lo que ha ocurrido.